# Cannot install Nuget Package Manager

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget, windows-7-x64

I am using VS2010 on Windows 7 (64 bits). When trying to install "Nuget Package Manager" from VS's "Extension Manager" it fails. The download works, but then I am stuck at the installing progress bar. When looking  in Windows' task manager yo can see that the installer keeps on starting up new instances of the "vsixinstaller.exe" process. It goes on and on until the computer ultimately crashes.

The same behaviour occurrs when starting the file "NuGet.Tools.vsix" directly.

I have searched the net for the solution but haven't been able to find anything useful.

Comment: This has been reported here too: http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2327

Comment: Can you try these steps please?

Close all instances of VS 
Examine the contents of HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ExtensionManager\PendingDeletions 
Delete the folders listed for each entry 
Delete HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ExtensionManager\PendingDeletions

Comment: Jeff, thanks for your suggestion. It turned out the problem dissapeared after re-installing Visual Studio and applying the latest SP.

Comment: @EmilLundin can you review my answer and determine that it is the best answer given?

Answer (score 3):

I received the same behavior today so I decided to open Process Monitor to investigate.

Guess what...Process Monitor gives the same behavior. Then the light bulb went off... :)

**Answer**: I previously had administrator privileges on my laptop, but those were removed at the beginning of the new year. For some reason, when these programs use credentials that are not in the administrator group, they recursively call themselves instead of failing, timing out or reporting access denied, etc.

Please ensure that your attempting to update after launching VS as an Administrator.

I will be providing this feedback to the [nuget support thread](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2327) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by installing Nuget with admin right under SP1.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution at NuGet Docs [Known Issues](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/known-issues).  Installing the hotfix they recommend even though I have SP1. It includes KB2581019.